# Trying to use a variable in a Python SQL Select Query

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to search a database filtering by a category which the user chooses and selects. I have attempted to add a Variable into my Select Query but it keeps failing with a SQL syntax error but I cannot find any syntax issues

```py
var1 = "World"
selectQ = """SELECT name, score FROM score WHERE category = %s"""
cursor.execute(selectQ, Var1)
```

The Error is `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1`

Comment: You have to fill in what `%s` is using C-style string formatting patterns.

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace of the syntax error you're seeing, as well as tag your RDBMS, in accordance with [ask]?

Comment: @James, no, `cursor.execute` will perform the substitution automatically (modulo `Var1` being an acceptable value).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64952928/5320906) on the linked duplicate Q&A.  You should ensure that the second argument to `cursor.execute` is inside a `list` or a `tuple`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below,

var1 = "World"

cursor.execute("SELECT name, score FROM score WHERE category = %s", (var1))

Note, the parameters should be passed as tuple.

Comment: No that just seems to throw up the same syntax error

Comment: Could you post your code and the error that you are facing here?

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
Should be in my question as well now

Comment: Apologies, missed this. If your parameter is only one variable to be passed. Use a tuple notation like this, (var1,). 

So your code goes as, 

cursor.execute("SELECT name, score FROM score WHERE category = %s", (var1,)).

Comment: Perfect that fixed it :)